# Copy paste not working on Virtual box 6.1 running Ubuntu 18.04 on Windows 10 Machine

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I am Using Virtual Box 6.1 and Ubuntu 18.04.

Here are my steps:

1. start the Ubuntu on a Virtual Box
2. in the VirtualBox guest window menubar, select `Devices`->`Install Guest Additions`
3. if prompted to automatically attempt to run software from the CD, just hit cancel
4. `sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic`
5. open a command-prompt window (`Applications`->`Accessories`->`Terminal`)

I have already enabled the copy/paste to bi-directional in the settings but still it is not working.
I have tried rebooting the machine too. What am I missing here, please help?

Also, I have tried -

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms virtualbox-guest-utils
```

Comment: Are the Guest Additions installed? Did you run `sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` after inserting the CD and changing the directory with `cd /media/<username>/VBox_GAs_6.1.*`?

Comment: virtualbox-guest-utils x86 virtualization solution - non-X11 guest utilities / virtualbox-guest-x11 x86 virtualization solution - X11 guest utilities

Comment: This has been officially reported here: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/19336

Answer (score 16):

There is actually a problem with 6.1.4 VBOX version. I posted the question in Oracle vbox forum and it worked after downgrading it to 6.1.2 VBox version.
Here is the link -

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=97052

Comment: been banging my head against the wall for 2 days now. Thanks for sharing. I'll downgrade also. One thing I've noticed was that the VM's that I've not upgraded the extension pack after the upgrade of the VirtualBox are still working as expected. The ones were I've update the extensions are the ones that stop working. So **DONT UPGRADE THE EXTENTION PACK and it should be fine**

Comment: I've got it to work with 6.1.4 by installing a test version of the guest addictions. you can this version at https://www.virtualbox.org/download/testcase/VBoxGuestAdditions_6.1.97-136310.iso

Comment: @BANJOSA that did the trick, I would recommend you post this as an answer to this as well, to give it more visibility.

Comment: done! thanks for validating that works @Richard

Comment: Is this broken again? Im on VBOX 6.1.36 and guest OS Ubuntu Server 22.04. I installed guest additions successfully as best I can tell and rebooted. Enabled bidirectional clipboard, but it's not working.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, there's something broken with the guest addictions.
In the guest VM's that I've upgraded the guest addictions the clipboard stopped working but in the VM's that I didn't upgrade it still works as expected.

There are two approaches to the issue:

1. Downgrade to 6.1.2 as referred above by @kurramkurram D
2. Install the test guest addiction pack 6.1.97-136310

The test guest addiction pack that solved the issue without having to downgrade the virtualbox version is located [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/download/testcase/VBoxGuestAdditions_6.1.97-136310.iso)

To accomplish the instalation all you need to do is mount the ISO as a CDROM in the guest OS and execute the install. After reboot the clipboard should work as expected.

Comment: The link you specified gives 404.

Answer (score 3):

I did the following and its working fine for me after the below commands. I was using 6.1.4 VBox and I have learnt there is a bug in VBox as it crashes clipboard which can be verified using `ps -ef | grep VB`. So, I have downloaded 6.1.2 instead of 6.1.4 and it worked for me. Posting here so it helps someone in future

#### Commands Starts

```
apt-get remove -y virtualbox-guest-x11
apt-get remove -y virtualbox-guest-dkms
apt-get remove -y virtualbox-guest-utils

reboot

wget https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.2/VBoxGuestAdditions_6.1.2.iso

mount VBoxGuestAdditions_6.1.2.iso /media/iso -o loop

/media/iso/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

If any yes or no question pops up then enter yes

```
reboot
```

#### Commands Ends

I got the above commands from https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=97052#p470890

Comment: It worked for me like this with 6.1.18 too

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 also needed this: sudo apt install gcc make perl – Michael Cole

Answer (score 2):

## The simplest thing that could possibly work:

1) Host Machine: Download 6.1.2 guest additions ISO

https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.2/VBoxGuestAdditions_6.1.2.iso

2) Host Machine: Devices -> Optical Drive -> Choose a file.

3) Guest Machine: The additions should run automatically once mounted to the drive.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 also needed this: `sudo apt install gcc make perl`

Comment: Correct. And now works with v6.1.8.

Comment: This fixed for me in 6.1.31 and 6.1.32

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, copy-paste not working between host & guest.

```
Host: Windows 10
Guest: CentOS 7 kernel version 3.10.0-1062.12.1.el7.x86_64
VirtualBox version: 6.1.4 r136177

Guest Additions Info:
filename:       /lib/modules/3.10.0-1062.12.1.el7.x86_64/misc/vboxguest.ko
version:        6.1.4 r136177
license:        GPL
description:    Oracle VM VirtualBox Guest Additions for Linux Module
author:         Oracle Corporation
retpoline:      Y
rhelversion:    7.7
srcversion:     5DCD7BDAC92DEED412B755F
alias:          pci:v000080EEd0000CAFEsv00000000sd00000000bc*sc*i*
depends:        
vermagic:       3.10.0-1062.12.1.el7.x86_64 SMP mod_unload modversions
```

**After upgrading the Guest additions to 6.1.5, the bidirectional copy-paste works!**

```
Guest Additions Info (after Guest additions upgrade):
filename:       /lib/modules/3.10.0-1062.12.1.el7.x86_64/misc/vboxguest.ko
version:        **6.1.5 r136459**
license:        GPL
description:    Oracle VM VirtualBox Guest Additions for Linux Module
author:         Oracle Corporation
retpoline:      Y
rhelversion:    7.7
srcversion:     930C0CE9CA34E7751A277F3
alias:          pci:v000080EEd0000CAFEsv00000000sd00000000bc*sc*i*
depends:        
vermagic:       3.10.0-1062.12.1.el7.x86_64 SMP mod_unload modversions
```

The Guest additions version 6.1.5 were downloaded from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Testbuilds

Comment: Nope, the latest 6.1.5 test build (6.1.5-136807 on Linux) still is unable to paste text.  Will have to purge out the VBox install and try the 6.1.2 build

Comment: @user280568 6.1.6 is out now. Perhaps, upgrade to that.

Comment: Didn't work under 6.1.6 either.  Dumped VBox.

Answer (score -1):

apt-get update && apt-get full-upgrade -y && apt-get autoremove -y && kali-setup && reboot

Enjoy

Comment: Has OP mentioned Kali anywhere?