# Fedora 31 - Guest Additions working - but shared folders do not

Tags: fedora, windows, virtualbox, file-sharing, shared-folders

Windows 10 build: 1909

Fedora version: 31, all recent updates from DNF

Virtualbox version: 6.0.14 (This is not quick to update, so please confirm that this is actually a problem before suggesting I update it)

**Here is what I have tried and checked so far:**

- Confirmed my user is in the `vboxsf` group
- `vboxsf`(along with `vboxguest` and `vboxvideo`) shows up in `lsmod`
- `vboxadd-service.service` and `vbox.service` show up in `systemctl` The `.service.service` is running, the other is `exited`.
- I tried removing and adding the shared folders in virtualbox's menu. Currently, the setup is: Folder path is my C drive, name is `C_DRIVE`, `Auto-mount` and `Make Permanent` are both set.
- If I remove the folders and restart my virtual machine, virtualbox re-creates them
- Checked the permissions. They were set to read-write-execute for both user and group, nothing for other.
- When I open the shared folder in Linux and search with `ls -a` it is empty, and when I try to make a soft link to something that should be inside it (something on the C drive) it fails when I attempt to use it, saying it does not exist. (Reflecting that it is empty)
- I uninstalled the `virtualbox-guest-additions` package (since it apparently causes issues), re-started, and then re-installed the guest additions via the "CD" it provides.

Why isn't it working?

Answer (score 1):

It was, in fact, Virtualbox. I updated to 6.1.4 and it's been fixed.

However, to install Guest Additions 6.1.4, I had to do:

`sudo dnf -y install gcc automake make kernel-headers dkms bzip2 libxcrypt-compat kernel-devel perl`

Because it turns out I was missing a few of those, and it would silently fail to install properly without it.

Also had to do:

```
KERN_DIR=/usr/src/kernels/`uname -r`
export KERN_DIR
```

Though copy/paste still doesn't work.

Comment: Copy & paste is broken in the Guest Additions 6.1.4-136177, see [Copy paste not working on Virtual box 6.1 running Ubuntu 18.04 on Windows 10 Machine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/569993/copy-paste-not-working-on-virtual-box-6-1-running-ubuntu-18-04-on-windows-10-mac).

Comment: Thank you Freddy! Once they do fix it, will there be any way to fix it without reinstalling VirtualBox? As far as I understand, you cannot have both the "CD" installation and the one you get from DNF, right?

Comment: Others have fixed it by installing the test build of the 6.1.5 Guest Additions from [virtualbox.org/wiki/Testbuilds](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Testbuilds).

Comment: That's all of virtualbox, so I'll take that as a no. Installing anything is a little tedious right now (unless it's portable/1 user only) so I guess I'll just wait. I'll keep it in mind, though, thank you. Is there also a known bug with a massive cursor in the guest? Darn, I picked a bad time to update.