# Copy Paste stops working after every guest reboot on VirtualBox 6.1 (Windows 11 host / Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS guest)

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I'm running Windows 11 with Ubuntu (latest as of writing just installed) guest.

To get copy paste working I enabled in VirtualBox then type this in command line:
sudo VBoxClient --clipboard

It works well. Though when I reboot Ubuntu I have to type that in again to make copy paste work.

How can I get this to permanently work?

I can't find anything online about this specific issue.

Sorry I'm pretty new to Linux.

Thanks

Comment: This could be a bug. Report to Oracle. https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Bugtracker

Answer (score 1):

did u see this answer here?

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/570165/525663

> There is actually a problem with 6.1.4 VBOX version. I posted the
> question in Oracle vbox forum and it worked after downgrading it to
> 6.1.2 VBox version. Here is the link -
>
> https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=97052

Comment: I didn't see it - so it's been broken for 18 months? Not looking good...